# LDAP Query to return OU which contains a given user

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need an LDAP query which returns the single OU in an Active Directory which in turn contains a given username (based on the samAccountName). Is that possible using a single LDAP query to an Active Directory?

Example: User with samAccountName abcd1234 is in OU=HR created under the main AD. I need a query returning the OU including its attributes, the only allowed parameter is the username.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: I never worked with LDAP queries before. I just know a Microsoft Page listing some example queries, but not the one I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require two LDAP queries. One to retrieve the DN of the user, then another that queries for the OU/container of the user based on a portion of the user's DN (minus their RDN). There is no way around it (That I'm familiar with anyway).